# Probability of a player being skilled given results observed

Tags: probability, bayesian, prior

Let's say we have a player playing a game. The player is either completely unskilled at the game, or is an expert at the game. We want to find out the probability that the player is an expert given his score.

Using Bayes' rule, we get $P[expert|score] = 1 - P[unskilled|score] = 1-\frac{P[score|unskilled]*P[unskilled]}{P[score|unskilled]*P[unskilled] + P[score|expert]*P[expert]}$

By $P[score]$ we mean the probability of obtaining a score at least as high as what we observed. Now, we can directly estimate $P[score|unskilled]$ by running loads of game simulations with a random player making random moves, and calculating the probability of getting a score at least as high as what we observed by chance alone. The other measures we have to get a subjective estimate of as we cannot estimate them directly.

The question I have is that I seem to be getting a counter-intuitive result with certain inputs. Let's say the player gets a highly negative score, such that $P[score|unskilled] \approx 1$ and $P[score|expert] \approx 1$. Plugging the values into the formula above, we get that $P[unskilled|score] = \frac{P[score|unskilled]*P[unskilled]}{P[score|unskilled]*P[unskilled] + P[score|expert]*P[expert]} = \frac{P[unskilled]}{P[unskilled] + P[expert]} = P[unskilled]$

So it seems that if the player gets a really poor score, we do not end up updating our prior belief! This seems counter-intuitive, as it seems that getting an incredibly poor score should give us a strong indication that the player is in fact unskilled.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Edit: of course, it does make sense that $P[unskilled | score >= highly\_negative\_score] = P[unskilled]$, as the condition nearly always holds. A better question then is, what is the best way of updating our estimate of player skill after we observe the score, if we know the distribution of scores for an unskilled player? Should the method be different depending on the observed score being low or high?

Comment: In your example, is p(score|expert) actually p(score > S|expert) or p(score = S | expert)? It seems unlikely that an expert would get a low score, but likely that the expert would exceed a low score?

Comment: The former - $P[score \geq S | expert]$. It makes sense if the score observed is high - then we are interested in the likelihood of getting a score at least as high by chance alone and the probability of being an expert if we observe a score at least as high. Using $P[score=S | unskilled]$ does not seem as useful, as we generally do not care about the probability of obtaining that *exact* score by an unskilled player but of getting a score higher than a certain amount. It seems like the method I propose works well if the score is high but not if it is low.